# How to change date-time format?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2014

I have a `RegDate` column of `nvarchar(max)` type in my table in which dates are stored in `mm/dd/yyyy` (5/22/2015 11:09:39 PM) and `dd-mm-yyyy` (19-05-2015 22:55:05) format. I want to get all these entries in one format i.e. `dd/mm/yyyy`. I tried to convert it by using

```
Convert(varchar(10),cast(vr.RegDate as DATETIME),105) as RegistrationDate
```

but it gives following error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Please help me regarding this problem.

Comment: This is yet another reason why you should always store your data with the appropriate data type. What sql server version are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine the format of the value you are converting before you can convert it. If it's simply between those two formats, you can simply search for `-` to determine it's format.

I would also suggest storing the value in a `datetime` column as opposed to a `varchar`, and if you can't do that for whatever reason, you should definitely store it in an ISO format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

Here's a sample that uses a case statement to provide optional formatting of your two date formats, using the presence of the `-` character:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ( RegDate VARCHAR(50) )

INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( RegDate )
VALUES  ( '5/22/2015 11:09:39 PM' ),
        ( '19-05-2015 22:55:05' )

SELECT  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', RegDate) != 0 
             THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, RegDate, 105)
             ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, RegDate, 101)
        END AS FormattedToDate
FROM    #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

**Produces:**

```
FormattedToDate
2015-05-22 23:09:39.000
2015-05-19 22:55:05.000
```